# How To Mass Attach Relationship Of Arrays Data From Imported Excel? Laravel, php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, import, relationship

I finally can import excel data into database(although different code from usual imports), but it fails to attach the relationship.

Three table: users(1st table), role_user(relationship table), and roles(2nd table)

error: Call to a member function roles() on boolean
[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDcBj.png)

UserImport.php

```
use App\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;

class UserImport implements ToModel
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new User([
        'nisn' => $row[1],
        'name' => $row[2],
        'username' => $row[3],
        'email' => $row[4],
        'kelas' => $row[5],
        'jabatan' => $row[6],
        'tempat_lahir' => $row[7],
        'tgl_lahir' => $row[8],
        'bulan_lahir' => $row[9],
        'tahun_lahir' => $row[10],
        'jenis_kelamin' => $row[11],
        'agama' => $row[12],
        'tahun_masuk' => $row[13],
        'no_telp' => $row[14],
        'password' => $row[15],
        ]);
    }
}
```

AdminController.php(partial)

```
public function import_student(Request $request) 
    {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'file' => 'required|mimes:csv,xls,xlsx'
    ]);
    $import = Excel::toArray(new UserImport(), $request->file('file'));
        foreach($import[0] as $row) {
            //  dd($row[1].' '.$row[2]);
            $arr[] = [
                // If uncomment this id from here, remove [0] from foreach
                // 'id' => $row[0], 
                'nisn' => $row[1],
                'name' => $row[2],
                'username' => $row[3],
                'email' => $row[4],
                'kelas' => $row[5],
                'jabatan' => $row[6],
                'tempat_lahir' => $row[7],
                'tgl_lahir' => $row[8],
                'bulan_lahir' => $row[9],
                'tahun_lahir' => $row[10],
                'jenis_kelamin' => $row[11],
                'agama' => $row[12],
                'tahun_masuk' => $row[13],
                'no_telp' => $row[14],
                'password' => Hash::make($row[15]),
            ];
        }
        if(!empty($arr)){
            User::insert($arr)->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'Student'));
        }    
    if($import) {
        //redirect
        return redirect()->back()->with(['success' => 'Data Berhasil Diimport!']);
    } else {
        //redirect
        return redirect()->back()->with(['error' => 'Data Gagal Diimport!']);
    }
    }
```

I check database and sure enough, import data from excel was a succes... it was just this code `->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'Student'));` seem only working when it's not multiple array data(only working in create, not insert).

Is there a way to mass attach relationship for all inserted arrays data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to mass attach relationship for all inserted arrays data?

Sadly, no. You'll have to implement custom logic to attach the role to the User you inserted. For instance, you could add a boolean column `is_importing` on the user you are currently importing.

First add the `is_importing` column to your users table, then:

```php
public function import_student(Request $request) 
    {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'file' => 'required|mimes:csv,xls,xlsx'
    ]);
    $import = Excel::toArray(new UserImport(), $request->file('file'));
        foreach($import[0] as $row) {
            //  dd($row[1].' '.$row[2]);
            $arr[] = [
                // If uncomment this id from here, remove [0] from foreach
                // 'id' => $row[0], 
                'nisn' => $row[1],
                'name' => $row[2],
                'username' => $row[3],
                'email' => $row[4],
                'kelas' => $row[5],
                'jabatan' => $row[6],
                'tempat_lahir' => $row[7],
                'tgl_lahir' => $row[8],
                'bulan_lahir' => $row[9],
                'tahun_lahir' => $row[10],
                'jenis_kelamin' => $row[11],
                'agama' => $row[12],
                'tahun_masuk' => $row[13],
                'no_telp' => $row[14],
                'password' => Hash::make($row[15]),
                'is_importing' => true // here we set importing to true, so our "not fully imported students" are marked
            ];
        }
        if(!empty($arr)){
            User::query()->insert($arr); //good, just be careful of the size limit of $arr, you may need to chunk it

            $role = Role::query()->where('name', 'Student')->first();

            $role->users()->syncWithoutDetaching(
               User::query()->where('is_importing', true)->pluck('id')
            ); 
            // we add all of users to the $role
            // don't forget to define the users relationship in your Role model

            User::query()->update(['is_importing' => false]);
            // we conclude our import by setting is_importing to false
        }    
    if($import) {
        //redirect
        return redirect()->back()->with(['success' => 'Data Berhasil Diimport!']);
    } else {
        //redirect
        return redirect()->back()->with(['error' => 'Data Gagal Diimport!']);
    }
}
```

---

Why you can't do `User::insert($arr)->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'Student'));`?

`User::insert()` is a shortcut to `User::query()->insert()` which allows you to insert data in bulk. It is useful because it's fast, but like `User::query()->update()`, it doesn't allow you to execute anything more than an insert query.

Said otherwise, calling...

```php
User::query()->insert([
   'col1' => 'val1',
   'col2' => 'val2',
]);
```

...is exactly like calling:

```php
DB::statement('INSERT INTO users (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2)');
```

It'll return you a boolean based on the query status (if it inserted things or not), but nothing else.

Therefore:

```php
User::insert($arr)->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'Student')); // Call to a member function roles() on boolean

// because insert() returns a boolean it's like writing

true->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'Student')); // Call to a member function roles() on boolean
```

---

Another problem in your code that you'll encounter right after your current issue, is that `->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'Student'))` will not work because `attach()` expects a model instance, an id or an array of id. Here you are giving a query builder (`Role::where('name', 'Student')`), you need to append `->first()`.

Comment: can I ask what type of data is in column of 'is_importing'  when I making it? I know it's boolean because true and false statement but just to be sure if it's need to be string data or another.

Comment: In your database, a boolean should be a `tinyint(1)` with a default value of `0` in this case. If you are adding it with a migration (the Laravel way), it is `$table->boolean('is_importing')`

Comment: Keep in mind that's just a way of doing this import, there are many others, some worst, some better, at the end only you can choose what's the "right" way of doing it since you know your requirements better than anyone here :)

Comment: I see you are new to stackoverflow, don't forget to validate the answer (here and in your other questions) if it solves your problems. This way, anyone with a similar issue can easily solves it :)

Comment: 9 month having this account but still new to all of this. Well, it fails when I did the usual User::import... but succeed in toArray... I will validate your answer after I tried it, still had another thing to do.

Comment: No problem :) If you have any question regarding your initial problem, feel free to ask.

Comment: It is working! Thank you very much, but before that... may be correcting this part 'User::query()->update(['is_importing' => false); ' it is missing ']' and resulting in unexpected ) error

Comment: Glad it works. The typo has been fixed. Have a nice day!

Comment: I hope you're having a nice day too!